# proguard.ParseException: Expecting separator ';' before 'sProcessGlobalConfig'

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, proguard

I'm using Cordova-android 12.0.1 and trying to obfuscate it with ProGuard 7.3.2 with instead of R8. However, whenever I try to build, it returns this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardTransformForRelease'.
> proguard.ParseException: Expecting separator ';' before 'sProcessGlobalConfig' in line 63 of file '/Users/macuser/Documents/bitbucket/my-app/packages/my-app/platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/proguard/configs/release/consumer-rules.pro'
```

This happens for any defaultConfiguration (normal, optimized, or debug) and happens when building for both debug or release. These are the proguard configurations I have in my module build.gradle:

```
proguard {
  configurations {
    debug {
        defaultConfiguration 'proguard-android-debug.txt'
    }
    release {
        defaultConfiguration 'proguard-android.txt'
    }
  }
}
```

and these are what's from lines 60-64 of consumer-rules.pro:

```
60 # Prevent ProcessGlobalConfig and member sProcessGlobalConfig from being renamed, since chromium
61 # depends on this name.
62 -keepnames public class androidx.webkit.ProcessGlobalConfig {
63     private static final * sProcessGlobalConfig;
64 }
```

Any idea what might be causing this error, and how I should go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered that this rule was being set by an outdated version of androidx webkit (1.4.0). Updated it and now it's fixed.

Comment: Answer is posted by Author of this question.